# How to pass a class component value to custom decorator in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decorator

When I tired to access an angular component value inside a custom decorator, I am getting an error stating `this` is not defined. From online documentation, I have found out that decorator function will get called first even before the class initialization. Because of this decorators will not have access to instance variables.

Note: I have tried creating a static variable and tried to access the static variable inside the custom decorator. Only problem with this approach is customDecorator runs first before assigning the value to static variable. Hence the AccountId is undefined when i tried to access inside customDecorator.

How I can access this `AccountId`  inside the custom decorator? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { Component,Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CustomDecorator } from '@sharedDecorators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-display',
  templateUrl: './accounts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account s.component.scss']
})
export class AccountsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() AccountId: string
  constructor() {
    
  }
  
  @CustomDecorator(this.AccountId)

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ...........................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hu Ane!

if AccountId is passed statically from parent you can simply:

```js
ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.AccountId)
  }
```

if AccountId is asynchronous you can do something like this

```js
@Input() get AccountId(value: string) {
 if(value) {
  this.accountID$.next(value)
 }
}

accountId$ = new ReplaySubject<any>()
ngOnInit() {
this.accountId$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x) )   <-- remember to unsubscribe
  }
```

[here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) you can find more info

Comment: Hi @Dario, Thanks for the quick help. Could you please tell me how we can pass `AccountId` as static from parent component? As far as I know, the scope for binding expressions in component template is the component class instance. Static variable is not accessible in parent component template. I am not able to find a way to pass `AccountId` as static from parent component.

Comment: in your parent component you can do `<child-component [AccountId]='accountId'></child-component>` . but you must be sure that you have yet accountId when the child-component is loaded

Comment: Hi @Dario, I have tried this. Unfortunately we cannot access class instance inside a decorator. This line will give an error `@CustomDecorator(this.AccountId)`

Comment: sorry @Ane but i nevere used custom decorator. i knew a `@change` decorator but Unfortunately i don't find the articles where i saw. instead this article maybe can help you  https://medium.com/@bharat.tiwari/intercept-input-property-change-in-angular-690567eb63ec